# Getting the value of first array from the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In php I have an array look like this.

```
Array ( [0] =>
  [1] => Array ([id] => 9 [slot] => 2 [name] => Test Ad [alt] => Test Ad [dimension_width] => 300 [dimension_height] => 400 [clicks] => 1 [start_date] => 06/07/2013 [end_date] => 07/07/2013 [status] => 1 [target] => http://images.google.com [image_url] => http://localhost/WebSites/coffee/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/uwp5-1-151553.jpeg [pre_exp_email] => 0 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [id] => 12 [slot] => 1 [name] => Test Ad [alt] => Test Ad [dimension_width] => 200 [dimension_height] => 300 [clicks] => 0 [start_date] => 06/08/2013 [end_date] => 07/08/2013 [status] => 1 [target] => http://facebook.com [image_url] => http://localhost/WebSites/coffee/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/uwp5-1-1515532.jpeg [pre_exp_email] => 0 )
  [3] => Array ( [id] => 14 [slot] => 1 [name] => Test Ad [alt] => Test Ad [dimension_width] => 200 [dimension_height] => 300 [clicks] => 0 [start_date] => 06/08/2013 [end_date] => 07/08/2013 [status] => 1 [target] => http://facebook.com [image_url] => http://localhost/WebSites/coffee/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/uwp5-1-1515532.jpeg [pre_exp_email] => 0 )
   )
```

From here I want to get the first value of array. For example I want to get the value of first array

```
[1] => Array ([id] => 9 [slot] => 2 [name] => Test Ad [alt] => Test Ad [dimension_width] => 300 [dimension_height] => 400 [clicks] => 1 [start_date] => 06/07/2013 [end_date] => 07/07/2013 [status] => 1 [target] => http://images.google.com [image_url] => http://localhost/WebSites/coffee/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/uwp5-1-151553.jpeg [pre_exp_email] => 0 )
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to get the value of 1st array?Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say all your array was in a variable $myArray, then

> myArray[1]

will give you your first array